# How to know which add-in is currently being loaded by Microsoft Word during launch?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

When launching Microsoft Word, I see that some add-ins are being loaded:

[image]

How to know which add-in word is currently being loaded in Microsoft Word?

I use Microsoft Word 2013 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: Do you want a list of all your enabled Add-ins, or do you want a live status on which add-in is currently being loaded while that "loading add-ins" bar is filling?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 live status on which add-in is currently being loaded.

Comment: What is the overall goal/actual problem you face? If you're trying to debug problems starting Word, then perhaps the [Telemetry Log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj230106.aspx) is what you're looking for?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Some add-ins take a while to load. Sometime the loading even gets stuck (e.g. it sometimes happens due to the Dragon NaturallySpeaking add-in).